# SQL Server output and return value in procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, return, out-parameters

I'm new to SQL Server, and i have this error that i was not able to fix:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure info, Line 11
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Steven' to data type int

Can you please show me where is the error, and how can I fix it?

The code is as follow thank you.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE info (@id int, @howMuch int OUTPUT) 
AS
   SELECT * 
   FROM emp 
   WHERE empno = @id;

   SELECT @howMuch = COUNT(*) 
   FROM emp;

   DECLARE @name varchar(100)

   SELECT @name = ename 
   FROM emp 
   WHERE empno = @id

   RETURN @name

-- execute the procedure. It throws error.
DECLARE @num_rows int, @who varchar(100)
EXECUTE @who = info 100, @num_rows OUTPUT

SELECT @num_rows, @who
```

Comment: I have noticed that:
If instead of using "return" I use "print" to visualize the "@name", the procedure works, and i see "@name".
It also works well if instead of "return" I put "@name" as an output parameter.
It seems that the error is only when using "return" to return @name.
Why is this?
What i'm missing to understand?

Comment: You misunderstand both what PRINT and RETURN does. Print pushes a value to the compiler while RETURN pushes a value to the caller, such as it defined by the query. Those rules are defined in [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) Typically, using a FUNCTION would be appropriate but you can also use OUPUT statement in your proc itself to return a value to the caller.

Comment: Yes, now I understand.
I did not understand the use of return.
I thought I could use a return with all types of data, and not just as int.
Now it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: Umm, you can return tabular functions/return different datatypes. I think you are giving up a bit too early.

Comment: Thank you. I know about using tabular functions, but i had misunderstood the use of the command "return" in procedure. Now i know that i can only return int datatype. I get confused in the example tutorial online of procedure returning the salary of the employees, and i thought i could return any information, including the employee's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of a stored procedure should always be of integer data type.
If you use a function, you could return other data types, but you can have only one value returned.

As you need two values out of the stored procedure, you could use two output parameters...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE info2 (@id int , @howMuch int OUTPUT, @name varchar(100) OUTPUT) AS
```

Comment: Yes, now I understand.
I did not understand the use of return.
I thought I could use a return with all types of data, and not just as int.
Now it is clear. Thank you.

Comment: This page has information on both the approaches of retuning data from a stored procedure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx

Though many of the usages I have seen refer 'return' for returning an error code, but it need not be the only case. In your example, you could return the value @howmuch as a return value instead of output parameter.

Often, I use return code for returning deleted count, inserted count etc.